# JSON serialisation of an array when I add data

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a form that allows me to input data about a single Item. Every time someone submits an Item, I want to add it to a JSON array, which is stored in a file.

Here's my code:

```
for (Item obj : list) {

    out.print(obj.getId());
    out.println("");
    out.print(obj.getProductName());
    out.println("");
    out.print(obj.getPrice());
    out.println("");
    out.print(obj.getType());
    out.println("");

}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file=new File("D:\\extern_2\\src\\java\\JSON\\jsonlist.json");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}



PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(print, list);
```

The problem is that every time I add a new Item, a new JSON array is created and appended to the existing file contents.

Desired output:

```
[ {
  "id" : 56,
  "productname" : "kklll",
  "price" : "56",
  "type" : "Hot Coffee",
  "productName" : "kklll"
    } , {
  "id" : 89,
  "productname" : "llll",
  "price" : "43",
  "type" : "Drinks",
  "productName" : "llll"
} ]
```

Actual output:

```
[ {
"id" : 56,
"productname" : "kklll",
"price" : "56",
"type" : "Hot Coffee",
"productName" : "kklll"
  } ][ {
"id" : 89,
"productname" : "llll",
"price" : "43",
"type" : "Drinks",
"productName" : "llll"
} ]
```

Why is it appending a new array instead of adding my new Item to the existing array?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `FileWriter` you are creating: `new FileWriter(file, true)`. [That second parameter tells the `FileWriter` to simply append information to the end of the file.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) If you are modifying existing JSON, you will need to overwrite the file every time. This means that the first time you create an `Item`, the `ObjectMapper` will write it out as a valid JSON string, representing an array with a single object. The second time you create an `Item`, it will do the same thing for your new object, creating an array with only one object (the second `Item`) and writing it to the file, even though that file already contains an array. At no point are you actually looking at the file to see if it contains any existing data. You are also not parsing your file into JSON, which would allow you to take an *existing* JSON array and add something to it.

Your process should be like this:

1. Read in your existing data in your file, using the `ObjectMapper`. Since your file contains an array of `Item` objects, you should end up with a `List<Item>` after you've read in your file
2. Add your new `Item` to the `List`
3. Convert your `List<Item>` to JSON and write it to your .json file. Make sure to overwrite your .json file, not just append to it.

Comment: I am not able to write the code for this if you could assist me please.